# How to set the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into certain column in timestamps function?

Tags: laravel-5, migration, database-migration

I am using Laravel 5.4, i read the docs said that, there are two function that use really similar name, it's `timestamps` and `timestamp`:

**Timestamps**

> `$table->timestamps();`
>
> Adds nullable `created_at` and `updated_at` `TIMESTAMP` equivalent columns.

**Timestamp**

> `$table->timestamp('name_column');`
>
> `TIMESTAMP` equivalent column.

As you can see, `timestamps` created a default two column, `created_at` and `updated_at` with default `TIMESTAMP` attribute. How could i make only one of the column, which `updated_at` have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute which just using a single command ?

I have done like below:

```
$table->timestamps()->useCurrent();
```

But i got an error instead using above command, so instead i used `default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))`. To solved this problem, i have to make two command, like below:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at');
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

How could i make that happen ?

Comment: Use ```$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();``` instead of ```$table->timestamps()->useCurrent();```. But as per my knowledge it`s not possible to it in single command.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh i am unable to use useCurrent() function, i dunno why

Comment: What error you are getting now?.